# Android Flickr Json Caching Images

Tags: android, arrays, json, caching, flickr

I am hoping someine can help me figure out how to cache the Flickr Json images to cache for faster loading and offline use...the code below is from a tutorial and i have all that figured out but am lost with trying to read/use the Android developer resources and other example on the web...be very grateful for a solution and help making this work...I am new to programming and appreciate the knowledge here :)

```
 package com.windmillagency;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;








import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidFlickrActivity extends BT_activity_base {



    public String thisActivityName = "Flickr";

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    BackgroundThread backgroundThread;

    public class FlickrImage {
        String Id;
        String Owner;
        String Secret;
        String Server;
        String Farm;
        String Title;

        Bitmap FlickrBitmap;

        FlickrImage(String _Id, String _Owner, String _Secret, 
                String _Server, String _Farm, String _Title){
            Id = _Id;
            Owner = _Owner;
            Secret = _Secret;
            Server = _Server;
            Farm = _Farm;
            Title = _Title;

            FlickrBitmap = preloadBitmap();
        }

        private Bitmap preloadBitmap(){
            Bitmap bm= null;

            String FlickrPhotoPath = 
                    "http://farm" + Farm + ".static.flickr.com/" 
                    + Server + "/" + Id + "_" + Secret + "_m.jpg";

            URL FlickrPhotoUrl = null;

            try {
                FlickrPhotoUrl = new URL(FlickrPhotoPath);

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection 
                    = (HttpURLConnection) FlickrPhotoUrl.openConnection();
                httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bm;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap(){
            return FlickrBitmap;
        }

    }

    class FlickrAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context context;
        private FlickrImage[] FlickrAdapterImage;;

        FlickrAdapter(Context c, FlickrImage[] fImage){
            context = c;
            FlickrAdapterImage = fImage;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return FlickrAdapterImage.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return FlickrAdapterImage[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView image;  
            if (convertView == null) {
                image = new ImageView(context);  
                image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);  
                image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);   
            } else {  
                image = (ImageView) convertView;    
            }  

            image.setImageBitmap(FlickrAdapterImage[position].getBitmap());

            return image; 
        }

    }

    FlickrImage[] myFlickrImage;

    /*
     * FlickrQuery = FlickrQuery_url 
     * + FlickrQuery_per_page 
     * + FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback 
     * + FlickrQuery_format
     * + FlickrQuery_tag + q
     * + FlickrQuery_key + FlickrApiKey
     */

    String FlickrQuery_url = "http://api.flickr.com/myflickrURL";
    String FlickrQuery_per_page = "&per_page=10";
    String FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback = "&nojsoncallback=1";
    String FlickrQuery_format = "&format=json";
    String FlickrQuery_tag = "&tags=";
    String FlickrQuery_key = "&api_key=";

    //  Apply your Flickr API:
    //  www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/?
    String FlickrApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


    final String DEFAULT_SEARCH = "flickr";

    EditText searchText;
    Button searchButton;

    Gallery photoBar;

    Bitmap bmFlickr;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.activityName = "AndroidFlickrActivity";
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onCreate"); 

        //reference to base layout..
            LinearLayout baseView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseView);

            //setup background colors...
            BT_viewUtilities.updateBackgroundColorsForScreen(this, this.screenData);

            //setup background images..
            if(backgroundImageWorkerThread == null){
                backgroundImageWorkerThread = new BackgroundImageWorkerThread();
                backgroundImageWorkerThread.start();
            }           

            //setup navigation bar...
            LinearLayout navBar = BT_viewUtilities.getNavBarForScreen(this, this.screenData);
            if(navBar != null){
                baseView.addView(navBar);
            }

            //inflate this screens layout file...
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View thisScreensView = vi.inflate(R.layout.flickr, null);

            //add the view to the base view...
            baseView.addView(thisScreensView);  

       searchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
        searchText.setText(DEFAULT_SEARCH);
        searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);

        photoBar = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.photobar);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(searchButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener searchButtonOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, 
                    "Progress", "Wait!");

            backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread();
            backgroundThread.setRunning(true);
            backgroundThread.start();




        }};


    private String QueryFlickr(String q){

        String qResult = null;

        String qString = 
                FlickrQuery_url 
                + FlickrQuery_per_page 
                + FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback 
                + FlickrQuery_format 
                + FlickrQuery_tag + q  
                + FlickrQuery_key + FlickrApiKey;

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(qString);

        try {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

            if (httpEntity != null){
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String stringReadLine = null;

                while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
                    }

                qResult = stringBuilder.toString();
                inputStream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return qResult;
    }

    private FlickrImage[] ParseJSON(String json){

        FlickrImage[] flickrImage = null;

        bmFlickr = null;
        String flickrId;
        String flickrOwner;
        String flickrSecret;
        String flickrServer;
        String flickrFarm;
        String flickrTitle;

        try {
            JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject Json_photos = JsonObject.getJSONObject("photos");
            JSONArray JsonArray_photo = Json_photos.getJSONArray("photo");

            flickrImage = new FlickrImage[JsonArray_photo.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray_photo.length(); i++){
                JSONObject FlickrPhoto = JsonArray_photo.getJSONObject(i);
                flickrId = FlickrPhoto.getString("id");
                flickrOwner = FlickrPhoto.getString("owner");
                flickrSecret = FlickrPhoto.getString("secret");
                flickrServer = FlickrPhoto.getString("server");
                flickrFarm = FlickrPhoto.getString("farm");
                flickrTitle = FlickrPhoto.getString("title");
                flickrImage[i] = new FlickrImage(flickrId, flickrOwner, flickrSecret,
                        flickrServer, flickrFarm, flickrTitle);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return flickrImage;
    }

    public class BackgroundThread extends Thread{
        volatile boolean running = false;
        int cnt;

        void setRunning(boolean b){
            running = b;    
            cnt = 10;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String searchQ = searchText.getText().toString();
            String searchResult = QueryFlickr(searchQ);

            myFlickrImage = ParseJSON(searchResult);


            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
        }
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            photoBar.setAdapter(new FlickrAdapter(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, myFlickrImage));
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, 
                    "Images Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) on github.

Universal Image Loader allows you to easily integrate asynchronous image loading, caching and rendering of images on Android in list, gallery and grid format. If you want to implement your own solution, reading the source for this project is a great way to start. It was written by [Sergey Tarasevich](https://github.com/nostra13) and is licensed under the [BSD 3-clause](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause).

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks really cool! I am wondering how the Flickr Json can work with Universal Image Uploader? Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look at the project's README doc. It shows a simple example of how to use the imageloader. JSON parsing is not done by this lib. You would retrieve and parse the Flickr JSON response in an AsyncTask. The imageloader is accessed in the Adapter's getView after you have built your ArrayList of image urls from the response.  That's where you plug in the url into the loader.